# How do I find the hidden units?

Tags: clash-of-heroes

There is a help text during the loading screen that talks about "secret units" that can be found during the campaign.

Unfortunately my PC is quite fast and it finished loading before I was able to read the whole text.

Are there really hidden units, apart from the 3 core units and 5 "special" units, and if so, how do I unlock them?

I already played the campaign to the beginning of the Silver Cities and haven't come across anything like that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this refers to those Units, which you don't get automatically, but need to find in the game world by doing quests for NPCs.

Take a look at a [List of these](http://guides.gamepressure.com/mightandmagicclashofheroes/guide.asp?ID=11833)